# allow user to select columns from data table on visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, datatable

We have lots of visualforce pages where we display search result to user in a data table. These data tables have large number of columns. We need to provide user functionality so that they can select specific columns which they find useful.

We need to  launch a dialog where user can select/deselect from available columns to be rendered in the data table.

Is there a reusable / easy way to implement this ?